# SQL Server how to update a column for a desired row number

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2000, row

Any idea how I can update a column but only for `row number=1` to `row number=10` for example?

Comment: Can you give more information, table schema and maybe the issue your trying to achieve.

Comment: rows 1 to 10 must be identifable. There is no implied or assumed order unless there is an ORDER BY somewhere

Comment: Unfortunmalety it's SQL Server 2000 !

Comment: There is no *implicit* row number in SQL Server - you need to be able to identify the rows you want to update by some column that's in the table, e.g. `UPDATE dbo.MyTable SET ..... WHERE SomeIDField = 42` or something

Answer (score 4):

This uses a derived table to isolate the 10 rows you want to update. Note, they *both* have an ORDER BY in them to determine the 10 rows

```
UPDATE
   T
SET
   SomeColumn = @newValue --or constant etc
FROM
   (
   SELECT
      *,
      ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY something) AS rn
   FROM
      SomeTable
   WHERE
      ...
   ) T
WHERE
   rn <= 10
```

Comment: when trying the second example I get this error message:Msg 4428, Level 16, State 1, Line 1
The derived table 't' is not updatable because the definition contains the TOP clause.

Comment: ROW_NUMBER(), OVER are not valid for SQL Server 2000. Unless the question is tagged incorrectly.

Comment: @Aaron Bertrand: we found this out an hour after this answer, as per OP's comment to his own question

Answer (score 1):

Generally, in Sql Server [Update](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa260662%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx) Statement is written as

```
Update <Table Name> Set <Column Name> = <Value> where <Search Condition>.
```

Comment: Then you need to explain how you know what row is "row number" 1, what row is "row number" 2, etc.